# Return void for a function type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a function for which I have explicitly defined that it should return void. If I return some value I get an error, which is correct of course.

```
function test(): void {
  return true; // Correct error: Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'void'.
}
```

But if I define a type for a function, which states that is must return void, and use that type, I do not get any errors, if I return some value from that function.

```
type FuncType = () => void;

const testWithType: FuncType = () => {
  return true; // No error, but it should be.
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAMQK4DsDGAVa8C8cAUAlHDgHxwBuA9gJYAmA3KKGlSgM5hxgycDqNMAAsssAFyJUmbCQLEycAN6g4cAE4wwSNSm5qkMUAF8mIUADMpYGm268wRCdXpKV6zdt1h9MU0aA)

Why is that behaviour, and how can I fix my type to get it work?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void